# Newtonsoft JToken Null or is it? ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

EDIT:  I think I figured it out.

Post had:

```
 m = '{" userID":"1"}';
```

Whilst Put had:

```
m = '{"userID":"1"}';
```

Note the difference?  That space changes the token.

Stupid me.
Stupid JavaScript.

Thanks to Shiva for working through it.

Original:

As a preface this is a personal project, for learning, best practice isn't something really worth writing a three page essay here.  Linking to one, however, is never a bad thing. ;)

So, I've run into the most delicious, nonsensical problem I've ever come across.  Using [FromBody] Value

```
// POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] JToken value){
        int b = (int)value.SelectToken("UserID");
    }
```

This returns "Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: value"

The Locals panel has:
+       value   {{
  "UserID": "1"
}}  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}

Okay, so it has a value. that's weird.  Even more so when

```
[HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody]JToken value){
        int b = (int)value.SelectToken("UserID");
    }
```

Works just fine.  Note the distinct lack of difference in the code.

Oh, the object I'm passing?

```
{{
  "UserID": "1"
}}
```

So, anyone have any guesses as what the heck is going on?  I'm bleeding brain cells at this point.

EDIT:  My lovely test AJAX call:  (Note, this is DELETE.)

```
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();

a.open("DELETE", "../api/manifests");
a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
a.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (a.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && a.status == "200") {
        alert("Manifest Created!");
        window.location = "../Portal/ViewManifest?mid="+d;
    }
}

m = '{"userID":"1"}';
a.send(m);
```

Comment: So the only difference between the 2 methods is the Verb? i.e. POST vs PUT?

Comment: Correct.  Same request headers, everything.  I built the PUT first, then copied to POST.

Comment: I'll post my ajax call then.  Like I said, weird.

Comment: Yeah.  That's how I got the locals panel.  Effin' weird. Note JToken needs a string, not a JSON object, that might be the null issue you're having.  Speaking of issues, I'm going to check for spaces or something.